# Detecting button click in embedded form with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, cognitoforms

I am using CognitoForms to embed a form in an iFrame. There are 2 buttons that the form generates, "Save", and "Submit". `onClick` of the "Save" button, I want to retrieve the saved form URL that it displays. Essentially when you click that "Save" button, CognitoForms will generate a URL to access the saved form, I want to `console.log` that.

```
<div class="cognito">
  <script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/VSqLsE7970G2a-Ir3-x6cg"></script>
  <script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "96" });</script>
</div>
```

Attempt: I tried to add the script in the first answer but it does not work. `Cognito.load` is working and the `reactJS` error I am getting is:

`Unexpected token, expected "}"`

```
<>
 <script src="https://www.cognitoforms.com/f/seamless.js" data-key="mydatakey" data-form="24"></script>
 <script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "24" },
  { 
          success: function() 
          { 
              console.log("form loaded sucessfully");
              ExoJQuery(function() 
              {
                    ExoJQuery(document).on('afterSubmit.cognito', function(e,data) 
                    {
                         console.log(data);
                    });
               });
           } 
   }); 
 </script>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<div class="cognito">
 <script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/VSqLsE7970G2a-Ir3-x6cg"></script>
 <script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "96" },
  { 
          success: function() 
          { 
              console.log("form loaded sucessfully");
              ExoJQuery(function() 
              {
                    ExoJQuery(document).on('afterSubmit.cognito', function(e,data) 
                    {
                         console.log(data);
                    });
               });
           } 
   }); 
 </script>
</div>
```

Inside the `data` object, you can find a property called `AdminLink` which can be accessed using `data.entry.AdminLink`. It should give you the value that you need. Hope that helps!

Reference link: [Client side events in Cognito forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/62/data-integration/client-side-events)

Comment: I have updated the question based on this answer. It does not seem to work... @inkredusk

Comment: @sfhasfasf If you directly copy the code in the answer, it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/v6c9qxfp/

Comment: But that is not with the "Save" button as per "Save and Resume"

Comment: I have tried using `beforeSubmit` instead but that does not detect the Save button @Unmitigated

Comment: @sfhasfasf: your form does not a "Save" button. It contains only "Submit" button. Please include the correct form in your question